# Give a rotating object on a canvas a tag that always faces North

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas with creatures generated onto it. These creatures move around the environment, rotating as they do so.

I'd like to tag these creatures with a small text-box describing their species that sits below them. I can make use of `ctx.fillText` to do so.

e.g,

```
fill(255,255,255);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "10px Avenir";
ctx.fillText("species_name",-16,20);
```

However, if this object rotates, so does the text. Is there any way of keep the text orientated north no matter the orientation of the object?

Comment: Inverse the rotation before drawing the text. Without seeing how you are currently rotating your object, hard to give you a real solution.

Comment: Before you draw the text add `ctx,setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y)` where x,y is the location of the left bottom of the text. Then render text with `ctx.fillText("Name of thing",0,0);` If you need to keep the transform  of the creature add `ctx.save()` befor the  and `ctx.restore()` after the code.